# What really means the position for a div?

Tags: css

When do we use 'position:relative' in a div, does it mean that the elements inside it will have a relative positioning or his own position will be relative to his parent?

Comment: Check out this article: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Comment: I wanted to VTC as "general reference", but sometimes you just have to go with the flow.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the div is positioned relative to its containing element.

Answer (score 0):

It means its own position will be relative to is closest *positioned* parent ("positioned" meaning any value for `position` other than `static`, or blank).

Absolutely relative positioned elements behave very similar, their position is also relative to the closest positioned parent. The difference is:

- `position: absolute`: the element is taken "out of the flow" when the layout is processed, so other elements behave as if the absolute element didn't exist.
- `position: relative`: the element is kept "in the flow" when the layout is processed, and other elements behave as if it has `position: static`.